# Working with extremely large strings in memory

Tags: python, memory, storage

my problem involves creating a series of extremely large modified strings defined by some tree structure. The root string is is on the order of 10^9 characters. I then generate 100 other strings (corresponding to nodes of the tree) of approximately the same length by various operations. The main issue I am facing is that these operations are interrelated via a tree structure. That is, if string number 5 and strings number 6 (if in the same subtree) can share some set of operations. With smaller strings, my approach was simple, as I maintained a dictionary for each string index and then just performed the operations traversing the root to leaf paths. Does anyone have an idea of how I can scale this approach to the larger strings because I cannot maintain a dictionary on the order of 100GB

Comment: Broad design questions like this are not really a good fit for SO. But I think a solution will probably involve putting the strings in files, and than just storing the filenames in the Python structures. When you need a particular string you read it into memory temporarily. You could probably implement a class that manages this automatically.